# Screen ramdomly crashes when hardware acceleration is activated

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

So, I installed Linux Mint 20 Ulyana today, and sometimes it decides to freeze and show garbled stuff. It only happens when I use hardware acceleration. It's seemingly random when it decides to do that. Disabling it seems to temporarily fix it, but makes chrome sooooo slow. Is there a way to fix it?

When I run `inxi -Fxxxrz` it outputs this:

```
System:
 Kernel: 5.4.0-52-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.6.7 wm: muffin 4.6.3 dm: LightDM 1.30.0 
 Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:
 Type: Desktop Mobo: INTEL model: H55 serial: <filter> 
 BIOS: American Megatrends v: 080015 date: 06/18/2019 
CPU:
 Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5 650 bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
 arch: Nehalem rev: 5 L2 cache: 4096 KiB 
 flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 25536 
 Speed: 1463 MHz min/max: 1200/3200 MHz boost: enabled Core speeds (MHz): 
 1: 1463 2: 1463 3: 1463 4: 1462 
Graphics:
 Device-1: Intel Core Processor Integrated Graphics driver: N/A 
 bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:0042 
 Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: vesa unloaded: fbdev,modesetting 
 resolution: 1280x1024~N/A 
 OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0 128 bits) 
 v: 4.5 Mesa 20.3.0-devel (git-a0b42da 2020-11-06 focal-oibaf-ppa) 
 compat-v: 3.1 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
 Device-1: Intel 5 Series/3400 Series High Definition Audio 
 driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 chip ID: 8086:3b56 
 Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-52-generic 
Network:
 Device-1: Realtek driver: r8169 v: kernel port: d800 bus ID: 01:00.0 
 chip ID: 10ec:8161 
 IF: enp1s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
 Device-2: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet driver: r8169 
 v: kernel port: e800 bus ID: 02:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8136 
 IF: ens128 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:
 Local Storage: total: 2.74 TiB used: 223.43 GiB (8.0%) 
 ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST33000651NS size: 2.73 TiB 
 speed: 3.0 Gb/s rotation: 7200 rpm serial: <filter> rev: G009 temp: 46 C 
 scheme: MBR 
 ID-2: /dev/sdb type: USB model: USB DISK 2.0 size: 14.46 GiB 
 serial: <filter> rev: PMAP scheme: MBR 
Partition:
 ID-1: / size: 733.80 GiB used: 62.99 GiB (8.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda4 
Sensors:
 System Temperatures: cpu: 47.0 C mobo: N/A 
 Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Repos:
 Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
 1: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main
 Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list 
 1: deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
 Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atareao-atareao-focal.list 
 1: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu focal main
 Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list 
 1: deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
 No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intellinuxgraphics.list 
 Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list 
 1: deb http://mint-packages.c3sl.ufpr.br ulyana main upstream import backport
 2: deb http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
 3: deb http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
 4: deb http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
 5: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
 6: deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ focal partner
 Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf-graphics-drivers-focal.list 
 1: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu focal main
 Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list 
 1: deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
 2: deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
Info:
 Processes: 252 Uptime: 39m Memory: 7.70 GiB used: 1.97 GiB (25.6%) 
 Init: systemd v: 245 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 alt: 9 Shell: bash 
 v: 5.0.17 running in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.0.38
```

Bug doesn't seem to happen when I boot in compatibility mode, or when the video drivers are disabled.
Here's how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A48Wy.jpg

EDIT: I am using the default display drivers and my bootloader is Grub2

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE ! It may not be a bug but rather a mis-configuration. Careful when using the _B-word_. Throwing it around may cause some to frown... Bugs are taken seriously :-|   ----- Can you tell us what Intel display driver and boot loader you use (if any in both cases) ? Please edit your post and add your answer at the end. ----- If you wish to respond, you can include `@Cbhihe` in a comment, if you want to notify me.

Comment: Kernel 5.4 is **very** old (a year old but it's developed very fast). Try installing and using 5.9.x and check if the issue persists.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Issue still persists on Kernel 5.9.6

Comment: File a bug report here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/groups/drm/-/issues Provide as much info as possible including `dmesg` output